# store an associative array in a file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am coding a module for drupal. In that I have a large associative array (around 1000 entries) which has key as 'string' and values as 'floats' .

```
eg. $array = array('hello' => 122.23, 'name' => 334.3 ....)
```

I was thinking of storing it in the database by serializing it.. but the array size is dynamic, so I thought of storing it in a file to reduce access time..

Which drupal7 api functions should I use in my .module to create the file, write content and read the array from the file and how are they better-off than the equivalent php file handling functions?

Note - This array is not used frequently so I don't want to store it as a persistent variable.

Comment: Why not make a DB table for those pairs?

Comment: @George Stocker - why is this off topic dude ??

Comment: @matt gibson- the array length(approx 1000 entries) is quite huge and will increase constantly.. so to store each key value pair in a separate row in the database and then combining all of them to regenerate the array will take too much time.. that is why I wanted to go ahead using simple files or store it in xml .

Comment: @George Stocker - why is this off topic dude ?? dude there aren't people as brilliant as you, and are still in the process of learning.. so if you can't help them out with the solution, then atleast don't demoralize them by closing their doubts and down-voting them.. i think its better to ask and be a fool for a minute than never to ask & be a fool forever !

Comment: @arjun this is likely better asked on the [drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) site. If you haven't already asked it there, let me know and I can migrate this there for you.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thanks man but I think there's no rule as such that Drupal related questions cannot be put up here. If you have a specific list of topics - softwares and programming languages , questions from only which can be asked here, then I'll be happy to look at that.. and btw there are about 9552+968 questions for drupal modules already here, so have you closed/migrated them also as off-topic ?

Comment: People down-voting/closing the question, I'd really appreciate a comment for your actions so that I know what went wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally wouldn't bother, I would just add it as a persistent variable using variable_set(). The variables table uses longblob so I can't see there being a problem, also the data is cached for quick access.

If you wanted to create a file and store it that way, you can find all the functions at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/group/file/7 though doing it this way would mean at least one hit to the database, as all files go through the file_managed table. Whereas if you store it as a persistent variable, the data is already available to your module without the need to query the database, as the data is already pulled during the Bootstrap process.

Comment: thanks.. I didnt know about the persistent variables.. ill use those

Comment: after reading this [link]http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15118/where-do-i-declare-a-global-variable/15124
i realized that persistent variables using variable_set and variable_get clear the cache everytime and since it persists between page requests & through all users.. it comes with a serious performance hit..

Comment: this also says persistent variables should not be used to store large amounts of data 
[link] http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7#comment-28439

Comment: It actually says "don't carelessly use variable_set() to store lots of data that you will only use on individual pages or in custom methods". Which is different to just saying "do not store lots of data". It depends how frequently you are changing those values, which you didn't mention in your question. If you values change a lot, I would create a table and stash it there. If you are worried about the serialized string being too long you should look at having a higher value for the max_allowed_packet setting in MySQL.

Comment: oh its my bad then.. nyways the data to be stored is not used so frequently so i think usage of persistent variables is out..